# 15 seconds to insert a single row in MYSQL 5.7 (happens occasionally)

Tags: innodb, mysql-5.7

I'm seeing very sporadic slow queries in MYSQL, at least, that's where Datadog is suggesting the issues are. I have, for example, 5 queries out of 726K traces (both selects & updates) in the last 48 hours which are slow. It seems to correlate with a spike in disk latency and or stolen CPU (however, there is ample spare capacity on the box).  I'm stumped and I'm unsure where to start trying to look for a fix (or even if it's worth attempting)

Here's the example with the 15 second COMMIT. It's doing a single insert into a `visitors` table. That table has ~5Million rows and the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `visitors` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `session_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `market_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_visitors_on_session_id` (`session_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=41764933 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

[image: query trace]

In this particular example, is it likely the index is being updated and that is causing this extreme spike? What's curious is that often these slow updates "cluster" (there'll be 4 or 5 transactions to different tables which are slow at the same time) In fact, with the example above of the 5 slow queries in the last 48 hours, they *all happened* within a second of eachother.

Any suggestions as to what might be causing this would be welcome.

#### slow traces (outline) below

The "COMMIT" and "BEGIN"s which are slow are for two different tables, both wrapping a transaction that updates a single row indexed by the primary key.

[image]

#### Update 1 - answering queries

1. There was no spike in iops or bulk transfer than I can see in the logs. There was a spike in disk latency and cpu.iowait (see attached)

[image]
2. I do have the slow query log enabled. It's gigantic because it's logging too much and hasn't been cleared in a long while. I probably need to reset it to work with it nicely - I'll look into that.
3. I don't have access to the host, but on the VM Datadog does report `stolen` cpu, and that's certainly ~ nil (it reports < .01% stolen cpu for the last month).

The provider did suggest changing the values for `sync_binlog` and
`innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit`. I've actually already set `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2` (we're fine with losing seconds or even minutes of data in the event of a crash). I haven't yet attempted to change `sync_binlog=0`, I need to understand a bit more about that. I wonder if that's likely to help?

### Update 2 - 9 month disk latency graph.

I thought this graph of disk latency for the last 9 months was interesting. It looks like something changed *somewhere* in our hosting provider (linode) environment around March 13th. Maybe a noisy neighbour, maybe something changed in the way their storage works. I'm following up with them about this in the hope that it may resolve the issues we've been seeing. While the graph just shows spikes of ~3ms, the underlying spikes are a lot higher.

[image: 9 month disk latency graph]

### Update 3 - values for Wilson Hauck

- `SELECT @@innodb_file_per_table;  = 1`
- `SELECT @@innodb_io_capacity; = 200`
- SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%flush%'; [image: flush values]
- uptime - 138437

Over the weekend I trialed changing the `sync_binlog` to zero. I still seem to get some odd slow queries in there.  For example, in the slow query log I see this one:

```
SET timestamp=1595871703;
SHOW /*!50000 ENGINE*/ INNODB STATUS;
# Time: 2020-07-27T17:41:43.145667Z
# 
# Query_time: 2.138283  Lock_time: 0.000169 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 1
SET timestamp=1595871703;
SELECT  `public_codes`.* FROM `public_codes` WHERE `public_codes`.`code` = 'fwreh7x1' LIMIT 1;
```

again corresponding with a spike in latency. Why would a query time like that be 2 seconds?

### Update 5

So, I reset the slow-query log. One interesting thing since then.. [datadog](https://datadog.com) for example reported 4.43 seconds to execute `UPDATE documents SET last_browse_path = ? WHERE documents . id = ?` (updating a single non-indexed column referenced by the primary key). However, I *do not see that* listed in the slow-query log, which, I imagine I should be seeing. Possibly Datadog is giving some spurious results?

### Update 6 - show create table result

Note, there are only 2.4 million rows in here, despite what the auto-increment says. We had an increment value of 10 for quite a long time.

```
CREATE TABLE `public_codes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `document_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `enabled` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `collaborative_editing` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_public_codes_on_document_id` (`document_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_public_codes_on_public_code` (`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17148900 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

### Update 7.

The provider was about to close the ticket and asked "was there anything else to add?", so I said how the issue was *still* happening, and how it was *weird* that something had changed on the 12th March but that I still had no idea what. At which point they said that *we had been live migrated to a new (shared) host on the 12th March*. They *had* mailed us, unfortunately we hadn't been monitoring the inbox.

I'm waiting to migrate the db box to a dedicated host as I suspect this is a [noisy neighbour issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing_issues#Performance_interference_and_noisy_neighbors) . Once I have done the migration (in a week or two hopefully) then I'll update the ticket here after that, assuming it fixes the issues.

Pretty annoyed they didn't tell me the first time I asked about the 12th March.. still, just hoping this resolves the issues.

Comment: What is the value returned from MySQL Command Prompt query SELECT @@innodb_file_per_table; and SELECT @@innodb_io_capacity; Do you have any SSD or NVME data storage? Could you post SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name; for the tables detected slow by DataDog and the complete query used for the updates?

Comment: Please also post TEXT results of A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%flush%'; and B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'uptime'; - you could be bumping heads with flush activity occasionally.

Comment: Do you have any SSD or NVME data storage? Please post TEXT result of SHOW CREATE TABLE public_codes;  Slow Query Log should stay ON 24x7 to allow daily monitoring.

Comment: Yip, slow query log is ON 24x7 - which is why I was surprised _not_ to see certain queries that datadog is reporting as slow in there. I will post the TEXT result shortly of the `public_codes` table, however, I honestly don't think there's anything special about that table (and the column it was selecting on is indexed)

Comment: I'll check about the `storage`, it's just linode and I think everything is SSD

Comment: 15 second commits and frequent disk latency spikes point at issues outside MySQL. Even if your vdisk is backed by NVME, a "noisy neighbour" or ten sharing hardware with you could do this. (You set `sync_binlog` to 0 at your own peril. Make sure you have good, tested backups.)

Comment: Are you on Dedicated or Shared services with Linode?  If DataDog is reporting stolen cycles, consider upgrading to a Dedicated service at Linode to avoid the cause likely cause of spikes.  Your use of ipinfo.io (requires your IP address) will reveal number of domains using your ipaddress.

Comment: Most of those spikes look like they are happening exactly 1 week apart.  Is this run in a cloud?  If so, ask the provider what happens weekly and when.  Perhaps an LVM snapshot?

Comment: @RickJames we do have a nightly backup process, but, these extra slow queries are happening outside that window. I added info above, the provider had migrated us to a new (shared) host on the 12th March. My hope is that we've just been seeing noisy neighbor periodic issues.

Comment: @WilsonHauck we are on shared services for this box. I am now planning on moving to a dedicated server as soon as practical and then I'll update the ticket assuming it fixes the issue. Makes sense, I should have tried it earlier but because I thought we hadn't changed host I didn't think too hard. That said, I guess it only takes one noisy neighbour. Anyway, thanks heaps for the suggestion - I bet it'll be the one that fixes the issue.

Comment: Patrick, How many ways is the server shared? Reported by ipinfo.io or myip.ms?  Dedicated will be in your favor.

Comment: Why have 3 unique keys?  It seems like `document_id` could be the `PRIMARY KEY`, and get rid of `id`.  This would speed up a variety of queries, at least a little.

Comment: Only 2 buffer_pool_pages_flushed per second -- very low.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a noisy neighbour issue. While we do still have some issues, migrating on linode to a dedicated CPU instance made most of these issues go away.

Comment: Please view my profile, Network profile for contact info and free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems to correlate with a spike in disk latency

> there'll be 4 or 5 transactions to different tables which are slow at the same time

Is there also a spike in disk throughput (either bulk transfer or IOPs?) also? If so then it may simply be a sudden glut of IO contention. Check to see if there are some nasty queries running around then that are scanning large tables/indexes or temporary increases in concurrency (i.e. you see an uptick in user activity at the time?, and/or are there scheduled maintenance jobs around then?)

> both wrapping a *transaction*

There could be locking issues here, with your update waiting for other transactions that hold read locks on the affected rows/pages/tables. Those waits might happen all the time, but are only noticeable due to one of the possibilities in my previous paragraph, or could be the issue on their own if caused by a single (or small number of) long running statement that holds relevant locks.

If you haven't already, enable the slow query log ([the documentation for mariadb](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/slow-query-log-overview/), IIRC it and mysql do not differ in this respect) as that may provide further clues if something significant comes up there at the same time as your visible issue.

> stolen CPU

That says you are running in a VM so there could be a lot of extra external causes for a temporary drop in performance if you can not find good reason internally. Do you have access to the host to check its logs/metrics, or only this guest?

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion to consider for your my.ini [mysqld] section

```
innodb-io-capacity=1900  # from 200 to allow higher IOPS for your SSD device
```

Consider running ANALYZE on your public_codes table to ensure indexes are current.

I suspect the slow query was bumping against some form of flushing activity that caused it to take 2 seconds.